# while and for loops with columns and rows

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

I am still having trouble display items through a while and for loop.  I have 5 items of data but only room for 3 items in a row.  What I want to achieve is to display the first 3 items in row 1 and the remaining 2 items in row 2.  The idea is the more items added, that it would just grow the amount of rows, but only display 3 items per row.  I got help yesterday but it only got me so far.  Looking for a little more help.  What is happening is that the first 3 items display in row 1 and then it goes to the next row, but the next row displays the same 3 items, not item 4 & 5.  I am inserting the code below:

```
<style type="text/css">
#static {width: 221px;padding: 0px 4px 0 4px; margin: 6px auto;}

#static .head {font-size: 12px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff; width: 164px; text-align:     center;padding: 2px 15px 4px 15px; margin: 0 0 0 4px; 
    background-image:    url(http://www.hot969boston.com/Pics/bg/nav/img_whiteTransparent.png); background-repeat:    repeat;border-radius:8px; -moz-border-radius:8px; }
#static .head:hover {padding: 2px 15px 4px 15px;  margin: 0 0 0 4px; width: 164px;     text-align: center; 
    background-image: url(http://www.hot969boston.com/Pics/bg/nav/img_blackTrans.png);  background-repeat: repeat;border-radius:8px; -moz-border-radius:8px; }


#static td.HOT969 .image{border: 2px solid #0083cb; text-align: center; padding: 0 0 0  0px; margin: 3px 0 4px 3px;}
#static td.HOT969 .image:hover{border: 2px solid #002156; text-align: center; padding: 0 0 0 0px; margin: 3px 0 4px 3px;}

#static .copy {font-size: 11px; font-weight:normal; color:#fff;margin: 4px 0 0px 0; padding: 0 10px 0 4px;line-height: 14px;}
#static td.HOT969 {background-color: #002156;color: #DFF2FF; font-size:12px; padding: 0 0 0 0px;  }

#static td.HOT969 a:link, #static td.HOT969 a:visited {display: block;border: 2px solid        #0083cb;font-size:16px;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none; height:230px;padding: 4px;}


#static td.HOT969 a:hover {display: block;border: 2px solid #002156;background: #0083cb;text-decoration:none;  height:230px;padding: 4px;}


</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/_SHARED/ApplicationData/Public/FlashWriter.aspx?    RotatorGroupID=5357", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("jpg");

document.write("<table border='0' width='675' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>");
var e = 0;
while (e < x.length) {
document.write("<tr>");

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
e = e + 1;
document.write("<td><table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' id='static' ><tr>    <td class='HOT969'><a href='");
document.write(x[i].attributes.getNamedItem("link").value);
document.write("'><img width='190' height='125' class='image' src='");
document.write(x[i].attributes.getNamedItem("image").value);
document.write("'><br><div class='head'>"); 
document.write(x[i].attributes.getNamedItem("head").value);
document.write("</div><div class='copy'>");
document.write(x[i].attributes.getNamedItem("desc").value);
document.write("</div></a></td></tr></table></td>");
}

document.write("</tr>");

}
document.write("</table>");

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

hmmmm... what if:

```
 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     document.write("<td><table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' id='static' ><tr>    <td class='HOT969'><a href='");
     document.write(x[e].attributes.getNamedItem("link").value);
     document.write("'><img width='190' height='125' class='image' src='");
     document.write(x[e].attributes.getNamedItem("image").value);
     document.write("'><br><div class='head'>"); 
     document.write(x[e].attributes.getNamedItem("head").value);
     document.write("</div><div class='copy'>");
     document.write(x[e].attributes.getNamedItem("desc").value);
     document.write("</div></a></td></tr></table></td>");
     e++;
 }
```

this way you wil be using the current eth element

Comment: That does not do anything.

Comment: Charlie, is there another approach to what I am trying to achieve?